# "roscore" is not initializing - ROS MELODIC

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS_MELODIC in my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS machine.

When I started the ros master with *roscore*, I got an exception as quoted.

```
... logging to /home/revan/.ros/log/199d6f5c-b3e9-11e8-b3b6-54a0507ac74b/roslaunch-revaapriyan-6988.log Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to interrupt Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB. 
RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: no such command [rosversion roslaunch]. 
Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/> The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

The Traceback in the log file:

```
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2018-09-09 10:00:37,367: RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: no such command [rosversion roslaunch]. 
Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2018-09-09 10:00:37,367: The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2018-09-09 10:00:37,368: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 322, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 277, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 226, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 138, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 447, in load_config_default
    load_roscore(loader, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 94, in load_roscore
    loader.load(f_roscore, config, core=True, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 751, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 723, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 657, in _recurse_load
    default_machine, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 667, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 282, in _param_tag
    "Invalid <param> tag: %s. \n\nParam xml is %s"%(e, tag.toxml()))
XmlParseException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: no such command [rosversion roslaunch]. Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
```

My env variables are set as:

```
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
```

PS: gcc version - 7.3.0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302778/%22roscore%22-is-not-initializing---ros-melodic/) by [revaapriyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37392/revaapriyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
Can you tell us how you installed ROS? Using `apt`, or did you build things from sources?

If you used `apt`, can you check that you have `python-rospkg` installed? It should be by default, but I've seen stranger things. Check the output of `dpkg -l | grep python-rospkg`.

**Comment by [revaapriyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37392/revaapriyan/) on 2018-09-09**:\

1. Installed ros by `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full`
   2.Terminal output for python-rospkg check.
   (a) python-rospkg                1.1.7-100  all  ROS package library
   (b) python-rospkg-modules  1.1.7-1     all  ROS package

PS: I'm using Anaconda Distribution for managing python package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> PS: I'm using Anaconda Distribution for managing python package

please try removing Anaconda from your `PATH` and see whether `roscore` can start then.

Most likely the `rospkg` module installed by `apt` is installed for the system Python and is not found by Anaconda.

That is why it then can't call `rosversion`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [revaapriyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37392/revaapriyan/) on 2018-09-12**:
Even then, I have the same issue. :(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-13**:
ok, let's take a step back.

Try this in a terminal:

```
rosversion
```

does that return any output?

If not, or just an error, run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-rospkg
```

**Comment by [revaapriyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37392/revaapriyan/) on 2018-09-13**:
it's working now after the `--reinstall` command. Thanks a Lot